# PHP Comparing Efficiency ($var == ($var1 || $var2))

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do the following if:

`if($var == $var1 || $var == $var2)`

I thought of

`if($var == ($var1 || $var2))` but that doesn't work at all. Excuse my noobish question, I never asked myself such a simple thing.

Comment: Why do you think the first statement is inefficient?

Comment: I don't think it's inefficient, I just wanted to know if there's a way to shorten the first statement, I am trying to make my code short and thus taking in account such methods. And I asked this question simply because I never used such sintax.

Comment: The second statement doesn't do what the first one does, you're comparing apples and oranges. Think about what each component of your statement does.  It's as if it were doing `$tmp1 = $var1 || $var2` followed by `if ($var1 == $tmp1)`

Comment: Or, to look at it another [better? :)] way, go in the parentheses order: `if($var == ($var1 || $var2))` if `$var2` or `$var2` are non-falsy becomes `if($var == (true))`, otherwise it becomes `if ($var == (false))`. Neither is what you're looking for.

Comment: @ShowTime - Why shorten code when it does not work as expected and/or make it unreadable and hence unmaintainable,

Comment: Both those statements are not equivalent. What's the point in comparing them then. Second one is not an alternate to your first  statement

Comment: @Ed Heal, I assumed the second alternative would be better, anyway I had my doubts cleared.

Comment: @All: He was looking for a way to compare a variable to two different other variables (prefably without having to write said variable twice). As you all (including himself) have said: the second example does *not* do the trick. For something like this to work for every type of variable, you would need some kind of inline-switch-statement. The closest to this (albeit usually not as *efficient*) would be using in_array, eg: `if (in_array($var, [$var1, $var2]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that you're taking 'efficiency' to mean *run time* (vs other measures such as number of keystrokes, e.g.) then what you originally have is as efficient as it gets:

```
if($var == $var1 || $var == $var2)
```

Conditional operators `||` and `&&` [short circuit](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) when they can, meaning if `$var` happens to equal `$var1`, then the comparison against `$var2` will never take place.

If you start to have many many conditions are you're just looking to keep your code clean, you can store all of the possible values in an array and check to see if `$var` is in the array:

```
$possibleVals = array( 1, 2, 3 );
$var = 1;
if(in_array($var, $possibleVals)) {
    // ...
```

That, however, is not nearly as efficient in terms of running time than if you listed out all of the comparisons individually (for a nominal number of elements you most likely wouldn't even notice a difference, though).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an `if` statement to define a variable there is. If you're running blocks of code in your if statement than your first example is the way to go.

```
$myvar = ($var == $var1) ? $var1 : $var2;
```

That's an example of the syntax, but you could also do something like this:

```
$myvar = ($var == $var1) ? $var1 : ($var == $var2) ? $var2 : "doesn't match";
```

Comment: Please put nested conditionals in parentheses, because PHP's behavior for them is not always easily noticable. The same reason you would add parentheses to "$x + $y * $z".

Comment: it's just a simple example. and no, it's not the same reason. putting parenthesis in an equation will actually change the result.

Comment: (x + y) * z != x + (y * z)

Comment: Yes, but I mean even if you know that "$x + $y * $z" will evaluate the multiplication first, and then the addition, it's still very helpful to write it as "$x + ($y * $z)", simply for readability and unambiguity.

Comment: i get what you're saying, but that's a matter of preference and the way i see it, the whole reason for using this method is shorten code, not legibility. If one was concerned about legibility they might consider using a full `if/else`. As far as I'm concerned the extra parenthesis are counter productive. But that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't factorize such a test like this, so there's no efficiency comparison to make in first place :)

### Explanation

#### First case

```
if($var == $var1 || $var == $var2)
```

It will pass whether `$var` equals to `$var1` or `$var2`, as expected.

#### Second case

```
if($var == ($var1 || $var2))
```

It will first make a logical OR between `$var1` and `$var2`, and test if whether one of these is true-ish, and return the result as a boolean.

Then, it'll compare $var with the former, which will be either `false` or `true`, and determine if `$var` is true-ish.

**See the other answers for workarounds!**

#### Personal advice

```
if(($var == $var1) || ($var == $var2))
```

To make the code clearer for future devs, you could wrap each condition in parenthesis (those are not mandatory, because of [precedence of `&&` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)), so there's no need to think about operators precedence at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

## Check out the `in_array` function

```
if (in_array($var, [$var1, $var2]))
```

### Efficiency?

This is a little less efficient than comparing the values individually (since an array needs to be created, walked through, etc.). 
However this issue is one that would definately fall into the category of micro-optimisation (and thus can be ignored) for all, but the rarest of situations.

### When to use?

It especially makes sense to use it when you have several values to check against:

```
if (in_array($var, [$var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, "test", 42, $var8])) // ...
if ($var == $var1 || $var == $var2 || $var == $var3 || $var == $var4 || $var == $var5 || $var == "test" || $var == 42 || $var == $var8) // ...
```

### Square brackets?

If you are not used to the "new" array syntax (`[..]`), here is the old (`array(..)`) one:

```
if (in_array($var, array($var1, $var2))
```